# Change the value of array field using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" name="fruits[]" value="Apple">
<input type="text" name="fruits[]" value="Banana">
<input type="text" name="fruits[]" value="Orange">
```

My question is how to change the value of "Orange" to "Grapes" using jquery?
The below code is not working.

```
<script>
    $("input[name='fruits[2]']").val("Grapes"); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(function(){ //<-- Add this in DOM ready wrapper as well
   $("input[name='fruits[]']").eq(2).val("Grapes"); 
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uPBv/)**

Answer (score 1):

1. The code needs to be executed in dom ready handler
2. your selector `input[name='fruits[2]']` looks for input elements with name `fruits[2]` instead of with name `fruits[]` and is at the 3rd index

So

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("input[name='fruits[]']:eq(2)").val("Grapes");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2rHGe/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[value='Orange']").val('Grapes');
```